# Why memset works wrong in apple clang compiler?

Tags: c++, macos, clang, memset

I found something strange doing problem solving with c++.

Initializing an integer array with loop works nice, but initializing it with memset function works wrong.

Below is the sample program.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 10;
const int INF = numeric_limits<int>::max();

int arr1[SIZE];
int arr2[SIZE];

void printArray(int *arr, int n)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%-10d ", arr[i]);
}

int main()
{
    // init with loop
    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        arr1[i] = INF;
    printf("\nINIT WITH LOOP\n");
    printArray(arr1, SIZE);

    // init with memset
    memset(arr2, INF, sizeof(arr2));
    printf("\nINIT WITH MEMSET\n");
    printArray(arr2, SIZE);

    return 0;
}
```

Result :

```
INIT WITH LOOP
2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 2147483647 
INIT WITH MEMSET
-1         -1         -1         -1         -1         -1         -1         -1         -1         -1
```

**Do I misunderstand how to use memset function? OR  Is it a bug?**

For your information, my compiler version is as follows.

```
kimseokjin@MacBook-Air LovePS % g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Just use `std::fill` in C++ and these sorts of mistakes go away.

Comment: `memset(arr, 63, sizeof arr)` should work in your case.

Comment: @amirali Have you tried?

Comment: If your question is "am I misusing X or is it a bug?", it is usually the former (unless it is a PHP question).

Comment: @DanielLangr I use it to set an array of integer to some sort of infinity number.

Comment: @amirali I understand, but you are trying to use a function that was not designed to be used that way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`memset` converts the second operand (argument) into `unsigned char` and copies it into all destination bytes. In your case, this resulting unsigned char is `0xFF`, which copied into all elements of type `int` gives their values -1.

Documentation link: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset.

*Recommendation:* Don't use low-level "C" functions like `memset` unless you are very sure of what you are doing and that you really need it. You don't need to set array values in a loop, we have *algorithms* in C++, such as `std::fill` suggested in comments. You might also want to use `std::array` instead of the plain "C" array.

A more C++-like and much more readable alternative:

```
std::array<int, SIZE> arr2;
std::fill(std::begin(arr2), std::end(arr2), INF);
```